# Color Correction using Color Checker

Tags: python, colors

[Comparison Image (Left: Original, Right: Color Corrected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm3Md.jpg)

I have used this example (https://github.com/colour-science/colour-checker-detection/blob/master/colour_checker_detection/examples/examples_detection.ipynb) to color correct the above image. But I get these lines after applying color correction, if u zoom these are red , green, blue line. And they rotate if I rotate the original image before processing. I am very new to this any help is appreciated.

Comment: please post the code in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue I was loading in RGBA image but the color matrices for swatches RGB , converting the image from RGBA to RGB solved it.

I used the following code to convert from RGBA to RGB:

```
cv2.cvtColor(colour.io.read_image(path), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```

Comment: You could also simply doing that: `colour.io.read_image(path)[..., 0:3]`

Comment: ah of course, I just realized that. Makes sense since it's a numpy array. Thank you for pointing it out.